# Adjusting/correcting a variable based on regression results

Tags: r, statistics, regression

I have a variable "X" that I believe can help predict outcome "Y", however I know that there are several other variables "A", "B", "C" that directly effect variable "X" in ways that will confound X's effect on Y. Essentially, I want to created corrected values of X that removes the effects of A/B/C. I will then use this adjusted value in a second regression model.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: So what is your question?

Comment: Doesn't seem much like a question, and especially not much like a programming question. Maybe try stats.stackexchange after some revision.